# How to tell wget to mirror website where links don't have html extension?

Tags: wget

I have website (book store) https://helion.pl that have links that look like this:

```
/kategoria/programowanie
```

There is probably one php application, and not actual files on the disk.

How can I mirror that website? I just want to have everything, except pdf files and images (images are on different domain).

I've tried this command:

```
wget -rmLk -U Mozilla --domains=helion.pl --wait=5 --reject-regex="pdf$" https://helion.pl/kategorie/ksiazki
```

but It download single index.html file.

Also some links have `htm` extension (without `t`) and they have `//helion.pl` in front.

NOTE: I want to mirror their site so I can use their partner program better (They provided xml files with books, but with missing data, so I want to mirror their site and after that, I will process it and extract information).

I'm using Fedora 29, if that change anything (need upgrade).